Replacement cord for a window air conditioner, what guage cord should it have if it's a 0651515LY with the numbers 14478 on the plug?
Cord guage for a replacement 120
volt Air conditioner to an extention cord

Depends current and cord insulation type, but generally match insulation type, calculate 125% of amperage from label on AC, and size application from NEC Table 400.5(A)(1) https://up.codes/viewer/colorado/nfpa-70-2023/chapter/4/equipment-for-general-use#400.5_(A)

A quick search of that number shows a 14 AWG 5-15 connector with a leakage detector. Assuming that (similar to GFCI, but different) is required either by local code or by the air conditioner manufacturer, then you need pretty much exactly that. As a more general rule:

If a device originally came with a 5-15 plug (15A or 20A circuit) then you replace with a 5-15 plug and 14 AWG (or larger).
If a device originally came with a 5-20 plug (20A circuit) then you replace with a 5-20 plug and 12 AWG (or larger).
If you don't have the original cord/plug and don't know what it looks like then you go to the power rating on the device. Generally speaking for a device like an air conditioner or heater (i.e., it gets used for a long time, as opposed to a hair dryer that is only used for a few minutes at a time), if it uses 1,440 W or less than it is designed for a 15A circuit and if it uses more than 1,500 W then it is designed for a 20A circuit. Between 1,440 W and 1,500 W it gets a little fuzzy and depends on how things are calculated.

The model # of the air conditioner should be enough to find a manual online which should give a definitive answer.
